# Python - StaticBox border cutted in Wxpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have created a very little application in python + wxpython. I need to create some widgets dinamically and it's exact what I do. But I have some problems with scrool: when the number of widget I created is less than the length of Scrolled Windows, the widget's border on the right (a staticbox) is cutted and if I resize the window manually using the mouse's cursor everything works. When the number of widgets is sufficient to cover all the page the scroll automatically appear and the layout is perfect. So how can i solve the problem when the number of widgets is poor?

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
import wx.aui

class Example(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
        size = wx.Size( 760,760 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

    self.InitUI()
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

def InitUI(self):

    self.number_of_added_mas = 0

    self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

    #Setup Main Container
    self.MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    self.ScrolledWindow = wx.ScrolledWindow( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
    self.ScrolledWindow.SetScrollRate( 5, 5 )
    self.ScrolledWindow.EnableScrolling(True,True)


    self.MainVerticalSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    bookStyle = wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE
    bookStyle &= ~(wx.aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB)
    self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self.ScrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, style=bookStyle )

    #Costruzione Master Sequence Tab
    self.MasterSequenceTab = wx.ScrolledWindow( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
    self.MasterSequenceTab.SetScrollRate( 5, 5 )
    self.MasterVSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

    MasterButtonSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

    self.ButtonAdd = wx.Button( self.MasterSequenceTab, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    MasterButtonSizer.Add( self.ButtonAdd, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
    self.ButtonAdd.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAddMaster)

    self.ButtonRemove = wx.Button( self.MasterSequenceTab, 1, u"Remove", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    MasterButtonSizer.Add( self.ButtonRemove, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
    self.ButtonRemove.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onRemovePanel)

    self.MasterVSizer.Add( MasterButtonSizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL, 5 )     

    self.onAddMaster(self)
    self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.MasterSequenceTab, u"Master Sequence", False )


    #Finalizzazione finestre
    self.MainVerticalSizer.Add( self.m_auinotebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
    self.MainSizer.Add( self.ScrolledWindow, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


def finalizeWindows(self):

    self.ScrolledWindow.SetSizer( self.MainVerticalSizer )
    self.ScrolledWindow.Layout()
    self.MainVerticalSizer.Fit( self.ScrolledWindow )

    self.SetSizer( self.MainSizer )
    self.Layout()
    self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

def onAddMaster(self, event):

    self.number_of_added_mas += 1

    self.panel_master = wx.Panel( self.MasterSequenceTab, 1+self.number_of_added_mas, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

    self.MastersbSizerAdded = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.StaticBox( self.panel_master, 100+self.number_of_added_mas, wx.EmptyString ),wx.VERTICAL )

    self.MasterCheckEnableAdded = wx.CheckBox( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 200+self.number_of_added_mas, u"Enable", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterCheckEnableAdded.SetValue(True)
    self.MastersbSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterCheckEnableAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5 )

    MasterfgSizerAdded = wx.FlexGridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

    self.MasterTextNomeAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, u"Nome", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextNomeAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterTextNomeAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterCtrlNomeAdded = wx.TextCtrl( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 300+self.number_of_added_mas, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 566,-1 ), 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterCtrlNomeAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterTextDescrizioneAdded = wx.StaticText( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, u"Descrizione     ", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
    self.MasterTextDescrizioneAdded.Wrap( -1 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterTextDescrizioneAdded, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MasterCtrlDescrizione1 = wx.TextCtrl( self.MastersbSizerAdded.GetStaticBox(), 400+self.number_of_added_mas, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 566,-1 ), 0 )
    MasterfgSizerAdded.Add( self.MasterCtrlDescrizione1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.MastersbSizerAdded.Add( MasterfgSizerAdded, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.panel_master.SetSizer( self.MastersbSizerAdded )
    self.panel_master.Layout()
    self.MastersbSizerAdded.Fit( self.panel_master )
    self.MasterVSizer.Add( self.panel_master, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL, 5 )     


    self.MasterSequenceTab.SetSizer( self.MasterVSizer )
    self.MasterSequenceTab.Layout()
    self.MasterVSizer.Fit( self.MasterSequenceTab )

    self.finalizeWindows()


def onRemovePanel(self, event): 

    if (event.GetId() == 1) and (self.number_of_added_mas > 0):
        panelToDestroy = self.MasterSequenceTab.FindWindowById(1+self.number_of_added_mas)  
        panelToDestroy.Destroy()
        self.number_of_added_mas -= 1

    self.finalizeWindows()



if __name__ == '__main__':

   app = wx.App()
   Example(None, title='Test')
   app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state the OS your are running. However, your code above it works fine fine on windows OS.

What you need to keep in mind is that the frame width size most be wider than that of the widgets.

[image]